# VueJs: Inertia event listener not working

Tags: vue.js, inertiajs

I am trying to use the event listeners with `inertia.post`, however I can't get it to do anything.

```
this.$inertia.post('/email/store', data, {
    onStart: () => this.sending = true, 
    onFinish: () => this.sending = false,
})
```

The actual post is working and it is being routed properly. However nothing else happens.
Is there anything else I have to do in addition to this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem. Unfortunately, it's not working as documented. :(

Since, the method is returning a promise, you can workaround like this:

```
this.sending = true
this.$inertia.post('/email/store', data)
  .then(() => this.sending = false);
```

EDIT:
[Events have been introduced with version 0.3](https://github.com/inertiajs/inertia/releases/tag/v0.3.0). Which version are you using?